# My Flutter app does not work on iOS 16 devices and works on iOS 17

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I uploaded the application to the Apple Store, and when it is downloaded on iOS 17 devices, it works without any problems, but when it is downloaded on iOS 16, it closes immediately when it is opened.
I've never had this problem before and I've spent a lot of time on it.
It causes me a lot of problems with the client.

I updated all the libraries and tried to change the code, but to no avail

my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 6.5.2+27

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.20
  lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.3.0
  device_info_plus: ^9.1.0
  flutter_offline: ^3.0.0
  data_connection_checker_tv: ^0.3.5-nullsafety
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.4
  firebase_messaging: ^14.0.4
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.9.1
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
  package_info_plus: ^4.2.0
  get: ^4.6.1
  lottie: ^2.7.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.2
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  dio: ^5.3.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/logo.png"

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - lang/

  fonts:
    - family: Tajawal
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Tajawal-Black.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Tajawal-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Tajawal-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Tajawal-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

my main

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox("user");
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('ar')],
      path: 'lang', // <-- change patch to your
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('ar'),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like your Flutter app is facing compatibility issues with iOS 16. First, make sure that your app and its dependencies are compatible with the iOS version you are targeting. In your pubspec.yaml file, you've set the minimum iOS version to 16.0.

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'
```

Ensure that all the dependencies you are using are compatible with iOS 16. Some packages may have minimum iOS version requirements, and if they are not compatible, it could lead to crashes on older iOS versions.